# How to connect confluent cloud schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

I am using Confluent managed Kafka cluster and Schema Registry service. I can manage connect confluent cloud kafka cluster adding following properties to producer config (Scala)

```
security.protocol
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm
sasl.mechanism
sasl.jaas.config
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
```

but can't connect to confluent cloud schema registry.
confluent cloud schema registry provides key and secret for accessing but I don't know how to set up the key and secret.
is there any config setting for accessing confluent cloud schema registry.

Comment: Isn't it just HTTPS? You have a user name and password in the client... Also cant you message Confluent Support with this question?

Comment: @cricket_007 found the solution

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following properties will solve the problem.

```
import io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClientConfig;


properties.put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE, "USER_INFO")
properties.put(SchemaRegistryClientConfig.USER_INFO_CONFIG, <SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KEY> + ":" + <SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SECRET>)
```